# H2O implicit conversion throws compilation error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

The code below is throwing an error when assigning the H2OFrame, most likely something is wrong in the implicit conversion. The error is:

> type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.h2o.RDD[Int] (which expands
>   to) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] required:
>   org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OFrame (which expands to) water.fvec.H2OFrame

and the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object App1 extends App{

         val conf = new SparkConf()
         conf.setAppName("Test")
         conf.setMaster("local[1]")
         conf.set("spark.executor.memory","1g");

         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

         val rawData = sc.textFile("c:\\spark\\data.csv")        
         val data = rawData.map(line => line.split(',').map(_.toDouble))    
         val response: RDD[Int] = data.map(row => row(0).toInt)

         val h2oResponse: H2OFrame = response   // <-- this line throws the error
         sc.stop

}
```

Comment: have you tried importing `h2oContext.implicits._` (it will implicity convert `RDD` to `H2OFrame`. Ref: http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.2/latest-stable/doc/tutorials/spark_h2o_conversions.html#converting-an-rdd-t-into-an-h2oframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is *h2oContext's implicits* as

```
import h2oContext.implicits._
val h2oResponse: H2OFrame = response.toDF()
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.h2o.RDD[Int]`

Comment: you would need `import sqlContext.implicits._` as well

Comment: why `sqlContext.implicits`? also, I don't have the variable `sqlContext`

Comment: .toDF() is available in sqlContext.implicits._ and you can create sqlContext as you created sparkContext

Comment: Now it compiles, but when I run I get `When using the Sparkling Water as Spark package via --packages option, the 'no.priv.garshol.duke:duke:1.2' dependency has to be specified explicitly due to a bug in Spark dependency resolution.`

Comment: Thats another issue @ps0604. I think the question is answered and solved . isn't it. :) you can ask another question for that.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368280/h2o-fails-on-h2ocontext-getorcreate