# H2O fails on H2OContext.getOrCreate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I'm trying to write a sample program in Scala/Spark/H2O. The program compiles, but throws an exception in `H2OContext.getOrCreate`:

```
object App1 extends App{

         val conf = new SparkConf()
         conf.setAppName("AppTest")
         conf.setMaster("local[1]")
         conf.set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

         val spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master("local")
            .appName("ApplicationController")
            .getOrCreate()

         import spark.implicits._  

         val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sess) // <--- error here
         import h2oContext.implicits._

         val rawData = sc.textFile("c:\\spark\\data.csv")        
         val data = rawData.map(line => line.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
         val response: RDD[Int] = data.map(row => row(0).toInt)

         val str = "count: " + response.count()
         val h2oResponse: H2OFrame = response.toDF

         sc.stop
         spark.stop
}
```

This is the exception log:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: When using the Sparkling Water as Spark
>   package via --packages option, the 'no.priv.garshol.duke:duke:1.2'
>   dependency has to be specified explicitly due to a bug in Spark
>   dependency resolution.    at
>   org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.init(H2OContext.scala:117)

Comment: are you using h20 as --packages while running the spark job?

Comment: No, I'm not running a Spark job, I'm running the Scala program referenced in the question.

Comment: This is how i am doing it  `import org.apache.spark.h2o._
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val h2oconf = new H2OConf(sc)
    val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc, h2oconf)`

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: did you solve this? I got the same error..